# function is not giving expected result, failing Unit Testing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a function `file_stats` that takes a  file name as parameter, and returns a tuple that contains three numbers: the number of lines, the number of words and the number of characters in the  file

I have wrote a code, that fails Unit Testing. But the output is fine.. Thanks in advance. How can it pass Unit Testing ?

```
num_lines = 0
num_words = 0
num_chars = 0

def file_stats(filename):  

   global num_lines, num_words, num_chars  

   with open(filename, 'r') as file:
       for line in file:
           words = line.split()
           num_lines += 1
           num_words += len(words)
           num_chars += len(line)

   tuple1 = (num_lines, num_words, num_chars)
   file.close()
   return tuple1
```

**SampleFile.txt**

LIET

```
Now, by Saint Peter's Church and Peter too,
He shall not make me there a joyful bride.
I wonder at this haste; that I must wed
Ere he, that should be husband, comes to woo.
I pray you, tell my lord and father, madam,
I will not marry yet; and, when I do, I swear,
It sh
```

**Expected Output** - (9,58,304)

Comment: Which version, 2 or 3?

Comment: i am using python version 3

Comment: Then why did you add a tag for 2.7?

Comment: oh so sorry, my apology

Comment: what if 'filename' file don't exist, where is the condition for that?

Comment: that will never happen.. i am not suppose to check that condition

Comment: Where do you get the Unit Test from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
global num_lines, num_words, num_chars
```

You are using global variables. If the unit test harness calls your function repeatedly, those variables will have been initialized only once, producing incorrect results.

Change your code to this instead:

```
def file_stats(filename):  

   num_lines, num_words, num_chars = (0,0,0)

   with open(filename, 'r') as file:
       for line in file:
           words = line.split()
           num_lines += 1
           num_words += len(words)
           num_chars += len(line)

   return (num_lines, num_words, num_chars)
```

You do not need to close the file manually, the context manager (`with open(...) as file`) will do that for you

Comment: i could able to do it .. but still for others.. it works fine.. thanks for your help